# NSDateFormatter returning null value

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to format a date using NSDateFormatter however for some dates, formatted the same way, it returns the time without the first digit, and for others it returns null.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
dateFormat.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_AU"];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:startString];
NSDate *endDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:endString];
```

This date: "Saturday 1/21/2017 17:00" will return (null)

This date: "Thursday 2/9/2017 14:00" will return 2017-09-02 04:00:00 +0000

This date: "Thursday 2/9/2017 20:30" will return 2017-09-02 10:30:00 +0000

Can anyone shed some light on where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: "dd/MM" : DAY/MONTH but "1/21/", clearly MONTH/DAY, because the 21th month... And in Australia, for the east part, you have -10 on GMT., so that's why it remove 10 hours.

Comment: Thank you for that. I figured that out just a second ago, thats what i get for trying to work late. Are you able to put that as an answer so I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EEEE dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` to `EEEE MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm`. Just a small mistake inverting days and months place.
Because, clearly "Saturday 1/21/2017 17:00", means the 21th of January, because the 21th month in a year doesn't exist (at least, not here).

For the 10h difference, it's due to time zones. In en_AU (east coast I guess), there is a 10h difference from GMT.